# Function as a Set of Ordered Pairs

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

Given the equation f(x) = 2x −1 to describe a functional association, write the function as a set of ordered pairs if the range is ℜ the real numbers and the domain is {0,1,2 }

Would the answer to this just be {(0,-1), (1,1), (2,3)}? Or am I thinking of this wrong?

Comment: Yes, that would be the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the domain is {0,1,2} then yes you can write given function as {(0,-1), (1,1),(2,3)} 
   Just f= {(x,f(x))|x is in domain}